# Get lat and lng based on my position from android phone

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I feel myself so lame, because what I want, it seems so obvious, but for me, it's not.

I am developing a game in my city, where I want to place some NFC tags, and players need to visit these places. I want to give them the exact lat and lng coordinates. And I am stuck at here.

I opened the google map application in my phone, and my location is shown on the map, but I just cant see anywhere these informations. I tried to do it in a browser, but the same situation.

Can somebody guide me, how can I get the coordiantes of my position?

I tried to save it into a google drive, but there is only a document only with a link, what show me the map, but not the requested informations.

Thanks, and sorry, if this is too lame.

Ps: that would be awesome, if somehow I could save it directly to my phone, because I need to place 50 tags, that would be hard to write it down, and then write back into the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several [GPS apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_gpsinfo) which, amongst others, display the exact coordinates on your screen. Some even offer to export them. Moreover, there are apps for [GPS tracking](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_tracking), recording your positions and usually allow you to export your recordings in [GPS eXchange Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_eXchange_Format) or [Keyhole Markup Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language). In both cases, exported files have the locations in plain ASCII.

For your case, a well suited app should support manual recording of [Waypoints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waypoint). This way you'd end up with exatly the locations recorded you want (and no extra ones).

A good choice would probably be [GPS Status & Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2), which in its [pro version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpstoolbox.pro) (~USD 3) allows you to a.o. "show/store/edit/export multiple waypoints".

[image: GPS Status] [image: GPS Status Pro] [image: GPS Status Pro]
*GPS Status & Toolbox* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2); click images for larger variants)

Note that the (implicated) other part of your question (how to process them for/in your app) is off-topic here, as this site is dedicated to end-users (not developers).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, it helped me a lot. I will use this too. Later, I found the solution. Go to my google maps, then I can add a marker, so later, when I finished, I can export that to KML too, and there will all the points. I will use both that, and this tool too. +1 for this nice, and linked answer.

Comment: Though I suspected there might be such a function in GMaps, I myself don't use GMaps too frequently (I avoid GApps on my Android devices as much as I can – they already know enough about me ;) – so I didn't know about it. But glad I was able to help! Enjoy the links, too :)